# using variable calculated wihin function on itself with setInterval

Tags: javascript

I have a method in my java code that is calculating the current price, i then use this in my javascript code shown below.

```
function updatePrice(id, currentPrice){

var newPrice = 0;
var cPrice = currentPrice;
cPrice = cPrice * 100;
if(rate == 1){
    newPrice = cPrice - 1;
}
if(rate == 2){

    newPrice = cPrice - 2;
}
if(rate == 3){

    newPrice = cPrice - 3;
}
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = newPrice/100;;
return newPrice / 100;
}



var nPrice = updatePrice('reverse', currentPrice); //The new calculated price, currentPrice is the price first injected into the script 
var timeinterval = setInterval(function() { nPrice = updatePrice('reverse', nPrice); }, 60000); //the nPrice as currentPrice
```

I want to be able to use the newPrice calculated in updatePrice on itself when running setInterval, so that once a minute the newPrice is being used to go down by 1, 2 or 3(pence);

Its probably something quite simple that i just havent noticed yet.

Hopefully this makes sense, fill free to request more info if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial issue is that you are not setting `nPrice` equal to the return value of `updatePrice('reverse', nPrice)`. As a result, every iteration will use the same value for `nPrice` and return the same result.

You can modify the code like so to get it to decrement:

```
var nPrice = updatePrice('reverse', currentPrice);
var timeinterval = setInterval(function() { nPrice = updatePrice('reverse', nPrice); }, 60000);
```

However, there are more things you can change to optimize your solution.

```js
function updatePrice(id, currentPrice, rate){
    var newPrice = 0;
    var cPrice = Number(currentPrice) * 100;
    newPrice = ((cPrice - rate) / 100).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById(id).innerText = newPrice;
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        updatePrice(id, newPrice, rate);
    }, 1000);
}

var rate = 1;
var currentPrice = 10;
var timeout = null;
// The new calculated price, currentPrice is the variable 
// first injected into the script from jsp
updatePrice('reverse', currentPrice, rate);
```

```html
<div id="reverse"></div>
```

Since your rate coincides with the amount you want to decrease, there is no need to have if statements to handle the different values of `rate`. You can simply say `cPrice - rate`.

You can also use a recursive setTimeout rather than a setInterval so that you do not have to update or keep track of any global variables.

Comment: Thanks for your help @mhodges, youve helped me gain a little more understanding. The problem im faced with is that i need to price to decrease automatically (which is why im using setInterval) however it doesnt seem to be doing this. I have to refresh the page for the value to change. Any ideas.

Comment: @HazardAGuess As long as currentPrice and rate are defined, my code would do exactly that. I will create a demo for you and also change up how it is working a little bit to fit some best practices.

Comment: @HazardAGuess Updated. Take a look

Comment: This is great @mhodges, runs well now, really appreciate your time.

Comment: @HazardAGuess Glad I could help =)